# PHP: Update database using script

Tags: php

Hi I'm having an issue with a small php script. I am trying to get my user to change the status of a "job" so I am having to use option and post.

I can get the option answer but not the id. So how do I pass the id to then new script bellow are the scripts.

```
<?php
$conx; //connection object to the server
$comd;//instance of a command object
$sql; //string variable to hold the SQL commands
$itemsAdded; //numeric var to hold num records added to table (1 or 0)
$dbpath;

$db = realpath("../Database/iceserv.mdb");

$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');

$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$db";

$conn->Open($connStr);

$sql = "SELECT callback.*,  status.stat_disc AS Status
FROM callback INNER JOIN  status ON callback.callback_STATID = status.stat_ID";

$rs = $conn->Execute($sql);
if (!$rs) {exit("Error in SQL");}
echo "<form method='post' action='../scripts/update_stat.php' id='status' name='status'><table><tr>";
echo "<th> Cutomer ID</th>";
echo "<th>Customer First Name</th>";
echo "<th>Customer Surname</th>";
echo "<th>Customer Phone Number</th>";
echo "<th>Customer Reason For Callback</th>";
echo "<th>Callback Status</th>";
echo "<th>Change Status</th>";
echo "<th></th>";

while (!$rs->EOF) {

     $callid=$rs->Fields['callback_ID']->Value;
     //echo $callid;
     $fname=$rs->Fields['callback_fname']->Value;
     $sname=$rs->Fields['callback_sname']->Value;
     $phone=$rs->Fields['callback_phnum']->Value;
     $reason=$rs->Fields['callback_reason']->Value;
     $status=$rs->Fields['Status']->Value;
     echo "<tr><td align='center'>$callid</td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>$fname</td>";
     echo "<td align = 'center'>$sname</td>";
     echo "<td align = 'center'>$phone</td>";
     echo "<td align = 'center'>$reason</td>";
     echo "<td align = 'center'>$status</td>";
     //echo "<td align = 'center'><input type='text' name='calledid' value = '$callid'></td>";
     echo"<td align = 'center'><select name ='status' size='1'>
     <option value =''>Choose status</option>
     <option value ='1'>Open </option>
     <option value ='2'>Waiting Qoute</option>
     <option value ='3'>Closed </option></td>
     </select>";
     echo  "<td><input type='submit' name='submit_btn' id='submit_btn' value='Update' class='submit_btn1'</input></td></tr></table></form>";

  exit;
  }
?>
```

So the above script is calling and pulling the information from the database

```
    <?php

    //variable listing and usage
    $conx; //connection object to the server
    $comd;//instance of a command object
    $sql_comd; //string variable to hold the SQL commands
    $itemsAdded; //numeric var to hold num records added to table (1 or 0)
    $dbpath;

        $db = realpath("../Database/iceserv.mdb");

        $conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');

        $connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$db";

        $conn->Open($connStr);
              $id = $_POST['callid'];
              echo "ID is " +$id;
              $option= $_POST['status'];

    $sql_comd="UPDATE callback
    SET callback_STATID=$option
    WHERE callback_ID=$id
    ";
    $conn->Execute($sql_comd);

//$result = null;
$conn = null;

header('Location: ../admin/callback.php');

?>
```

The above script is trying to update the table but the id is not passing through so how do I get the ID to be passed to the script?

Please ask if ive been unclear

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, but I want to point out that you have yourself wide open to SQL injection.  Please read up on using prepared queries with PDO.  In addition, you cannot use relative paths in a 302 redirect (which is what you are doing with the location header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of the select like: `<option value ='{$callid}|1'>Open </option>` and then explode by "|" to split the result `list($id,$option)=explode("|",$_REQUEST['status'])`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response would I do this on the update script ie second script?

Comment: @andy the first part in the html and the second in the action script (don't forget to replace $_REQUEST['status'] with $option)

Comment: that worked thank you very much.  I'll know work on stoping my scripts being open to SQL injections thank you

Comment: @andy - better use my solution :) it is straight forward and not a workaround like messing up 2 data in one field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="calledid" value="<?=$callid;?>" />
```

My bad.

```
<button name="calledid" type="submit" value="<?=$callid;?>">Submit</button>
```

Use it instead of your input.

Comment: bad ideea...he only needs one callid (for one specific row)